# Why is Interfaces behaviour different when using value types and reference types

Tags: c#, interface, value-type, reference-type

I did the following example in c#

```
    interface IChangeable
    {
        void Change(params Int32[] array);
    }

    struct SomeValueType : IChangeable
    {
        private Int32 m_X;

        public SomeValueType(int X)
        {
            m_X = X;
        }

        public void Change(params Int32[] array)
        {
            m_X = array[0];
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("Crt value of m_X: {0}", m_X);
        }
    }
```

And in Main:

```
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        SomeValueType someValueType = new SomeValueType(5);
        Console.WriteLine(someValueType);                                   // No boxing occured. It showed: 5

        Object someRefType = someValueType;                                 // Boxed
        Console.WriteLine(someRefType);                                     // Also Shows 5 (from heap)

        someValueType.Change(2);                                            // Change Value of x not o's
        Console.WriteLine(someValueType + " " + someRefType);               // 2 5

        ((SomeValueType)someRefType).Change(3);                             // Copies to a temp stack so no change ocuured in o
        Console.WriteLine(someRefType);                                     // 5

        IChangeable itfStackChange = (IChangeable)someValueType;
        itfStackChange.Change(7);
        Console.WriteLine(someValueType);                                   // Shows 2 and not 7 ... why?

        IChangeable itfChange = (IChangeable)someRefType;
        itfChange.Change(1);                                                // Unboxes the value of o, making the value of x 1 boxes o again?
        Console.WriteLine(someRefType);                                     // Shows 1
    }
```

Now I am wondering what happens when I do:

```
        IChangeable itfStackChange = (IChangeable)someValueType;      //value was 2 and its still 2
        itfStackChange.Change(7);
        Console.WriteLine(someValueType);
```

But if I change the definition of struct to class like in:

```
class SomeValueType : IChangeable
```

It writes 7 and not 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value types semantics are such that the value gets *copied* on assignment. This means that when you change after assignment, the variables point to different objects.

For reference types the *reference* gets copied, meaning that when you change after assignment, both variables point to the same object.

See [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: So when I wrote IChangeable itfStackChange = (IChangeable)someValueType;  itfStackChange points to a copied value of someValueType and I am modifying that copied value?

Comment: It's important to note that if one stores a value type to a variable of interface type, the system will create a new heap object instance and store a reference to that; that new instance will behave in many ways like a reference type, and will exhibit reference-type semantics.

Answer (score 0):

A structure-type definition actually defines two kinds of things: a kind of storage location, and a kind of heap object which inherits from the abstract class `System.ValueType`.  The heap object effectively has one field of the corresponding storage-location type, but exposes all the members of that storage-location type as though they were its own.  To the outside world, the heap type will behave like a class object; internally, however, references to `this` are references to its field of the corresponding storage-location type.

Although C# defines the term "inheritance" in such a way as to pretend that the storage-location type and the heap-object type are one and the same, the two types will behave differently.  Casting a value type to an interface that it represents will generate a new heap object which holds a copy of the public and private fields of the value type that was cast, and then return a reference to that new instance.  The resulting reference will exhibit reference semantics, since it will be a reference.

If one regards heap objects and value-type storage locations as existing in separate universes, and recognizes the cases in which values must be copied from one universe to the other, one will find that such a model will accurately predict how things will behave.